# React-Native performance with Text components

Tags: android, performance, react-native

When generating a page with React-Native on Android with 40 buttons (simple colored squares) with three `Text` strings per button, the performance is bad: 300+ ms on for example a Galaxy Tab 2 (ok, a bit older) and 100+ ms on state-of-that Android phones.

When omitting the `Text` components, displaying just colored squares, the performance is much better (down to 30%), so it looks like most of the time is used for displaying the strings.  When displaying only a few buttons i.s.o. 40, performance is ok too.

I've stripped down the environment (left out redux, navigation, animation etc.) to a bare minimum, so this is a just doing the basic rendering. The dev-mode setting is disabled.

My question: is it normal in React-Native that a simple page layout with a few hundred text strings can not be displayed in a reasonably short time, so that it looks like it appears "instantaneously"?